# Repeated-measures ANOVA vs. Friedman-Test (normality?)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, repeated-measures, normality-assumption, qq-plot, friedman-test

I've four (paired) datasets consisting of 43 rows and want to check if there is statistically significant change between those groups. To see whether a repeated-measure anova or it's non-parametric alternative (Friedman test) is applicable, I've plotted some density-plots to get a rough overview on data-distribution of each "group" which outputs the following:

[image]

As there are signs of skewness and bimodality I've drawn some Q-Q-Plots to investigate further. Q-Q-Plots look like this:

[image]

If I interpret this correctly, the data follow the straight line very roughly, although there are some outliers on the left and right tails that may indicate skewness and therefore asymmetric behavior of the data. So I've also performed some Shapiro-Wilk normality test for each of the four groups to provide some arguments why to use one hypothesis test over the other (ANOVA vs. Friedman).

In my opinion the outputs are quite contradictory. Based on the density & Q-Q-Plots the data can not be assumed to be normally distributed. In addition shapiro-wilk tests show p-values all greater than .05 (p = .1082, p = .155, p = .09552, p = .2541). I know such normality-tests should be used with caution, but I am not sure which hypothesis test I should go with based on all those outputs. I don't know if I provided enough information, but do you suggest to use a repeated-measure ANOVA or Friedman-Test (including pairwise post-hoc tests to see where the differences may occur) in this case?

Thank you for your help!